# Where i find a list of Key Equivalent strings on MacOSX

Tags: cocoa, macos

I need to know which NSString values i can use for key equivalents.

I can't find out what to use for

- cursor keys
- delete/backspace
- function keys
- numpad items

Comment: Okay i found delete is character 127 and backspace is character 8

Answer (score 3):

See **Button Programming Topics**: **Setting a Button’s Key Equivalent**:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Button/Tasks/SettingButtonKeyEquiv.html

For a single character:

```
[button setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"];
```

For a non-print character:

```
unichar left = NSLeftArrowFunctionKey;
[button setKeyEquivalent:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&left length:1]];
```

Buttons and menu items use the same APIs for key equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the key equivalent strings is simply the character that the key enters. For the text-editing keys, there are symbolic constants for each character defined in NSText.h and [documented in NSText's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000367-SW46). Use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", desiredCharacterGoesHere]` to convert these to NSStrings for use with objects such as NSMenuItems.

The same goes for the keys on the numeric keypad, which aren't distinguished from their cousins in the main keyboard. We are dealing with *characters* here, after all, and both sets of keys enter the same characters. I don't think there is a way to set a menu's key code rather than its key-equivalent character; you would need to implement this yourself.

Note that “delete” (as the opposite of backspace) is called “forward delete” on the Mac, as backspace is usually called delete.

Comment: And what about function keys?

I found a way to display them as key equivalent in menus but they are not invoked. The argument with the character might be right (well backspace/enter is not a character either) but it only gives Apple a bad name. Their Key handling is so terrible broken anyway.

Comment: Backspace is a character (ASCII #8, exactly the character that gets bound to it when you set it in IB), and Apple's key handling is not “terrible broken”. If it were, it wouldn't work so well with other key layouts; in my experience as a Dvorak user, it's always custom key handling that screws that up. See WWDC 2010 session 145 to learn how Apple's key handling works; it's an elegant, flexible system. As for the function keys, those are defined in NSEvent.h. Incidentally, I noticed a key modifier mask there for keypad keys; you could set that on any menu items that should be keypad-specific.

Comment: I just tested, and it doesn't help—the menu item matches the character regardless of whether the menu item has `NSNumericPadKeyMask`. Sounds like a bug to me, so I suggest filing it: https://bugreport.apple.com/ In the meantime, you can use the information in #145 to handle that yourself.

Comment: Hi Peter,can you please share the program you wrote for finding the key equivalents?

Comment: @deovrat singh: I just rewrote my answer to suggest a better way of doing it. For everything else (e.g., function keys), use Many Tricks's program Key Codes. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12